# Can I use TombstoneHelper Class in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I had Windows Phone 8. When I put my app in background and then when I start after some time it seems me a black because of Tombstone. I have found the solution which is the `TombstoneHelper` class. But I had a little question whether it can support Windows Phone 8. Because everywhere I look I only found Wp7 `TombstoneHelper`. So it is a little confusing.I had two TextBox in my app they comes null after Tombstone.Here is my xaml Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Firstname :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Text="" 
         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Lastname :" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox 
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And the C# code is :

```
 `public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void znNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.SaveState(e, typeof(TextBox));
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RestoreState();
    }`
```

Comment: yes you can easily use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use it. See my [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/mrlacey/status/408487706923384832) with [Matt Lacey](https://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/mrlacey), the man behind [TombstoneHelper](https://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/)

[image]